# Converting decimal to binary

Tags: iphone, base-conversion

I want to convert decimal number in binary number. I'm using this method:

```
- (NSMutableString*)intStringToBinary:(long long)element{
    NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];
    for(NSInteger numberCopy = element; numberCopy > 0; numberCopy >>= 1)
    {
        [str insertString:((numberCopy & 1) ? @"1" : @"0") atIndex:0];
    }
    return str;
}
```

everything is going fine if the number "element" is >0. If the number is <0 there is the problem. For examle the method can't convert the number "-1". What can i do to solve the problem? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You are potentially leaking memory, you should be returning an autoreleased mutable string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an extra bit for the sign.

Example:

`1xxxx` represents the binary number `+ xxxx`.

`0yyyy` represents the binary number `- yyyy`.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a way to do it in Python using Wallar's Algorithm. The input and output are lists.

```
from math import *
def baseExpansion(n,c,b):
    j = 0
    base10 = sum([pow(c,len(n)-k-1)*n[k] for k in range(0,len(n))])
    while floor(base10/pow(b,j)) != 0: j = j+1
    return [floor(base10/pow(b,j-p)) % b for p in range(1,j+1)]
```